# mobile virtualization - running multiple os's

Tags: mobile, virtualization

i have used desktop virtualization solutions and i know that it supports the running of multiple completely different operating systems. However i am intrigued to know whether mobile phone virtualization solution also provide running of say android, windows mobile , and perhaps iphone os on the same mobile phone ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For more info take a look at [this presentation](http://webpages.iust.ac.ir/hsalimi/Courses/88-89-1/VM/Slides/VT-Mobile.pptx) and its references prepared by one of my students.